# Euclidean distance with weights

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, euclidean-distance

I am currently using `SciPy` to calculate the euclidean distance

```
dis = scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean(A,B)
```

where; A, B are 5-dimension bit vectors. It works fine now, but if I add weights for each dimension then, is it still possible to use scipy?

What I have now: `sqrt((a1-b1)^2 + (a2-b2)^2 +...+ (a5-b5)^2)`

What I want: `sqrt(w1(a1-b1)^2 + w2(a2-b2)^2 +...+ w5(a5-b5)^2)` using scipy or numpy or any other efficient way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The suggestion of writing your own weighted L2 norm is a good one, but the calculation provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8860933/681865) is incorrect. If the intention is to calculate

[image]

then this should do the job:

```
def weightedL2(a,b,w):
    q = a-b
    return np.sqrt((w*q*q).sum())
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply define it yourself.  Something like this should do the trick:

```
def mynorm(A, B, w):
    import numpy as np
    q = np.matrix(w * (A - B))
    return np.sqrt((q * q.T).sum())
```

Comment: That isn't the norm contained in the question - you have squared the weights. Also the `.sum()` is completely redundant, `q*q.T` is the inner product of the vector with itself, ie. it *is* the sum.

Comment: You are correct about the weights, I should have been more careful, however your criticism about the `.sum()` being completely redundant is misguided.  The result of `q * q.T` would be a 1x1 matrix, which would be an unexpected return type for a norm function, the sum will turn it into a scalar.

Comment: But why use `sum()` to cast to a scalar? `np.asscalar`  will be several times faster`?

Comment: I don't know the reason, but that is how it is implemented in `scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean` .. I just assume the authors of scipy know what's best

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep using scipy function you could pre-process the vector like this.

```
def weighted_euclidean(a, b, w):
    A = a*np.sqrt(w)
    B = b*np.sqrt(w)
    return scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean(A, B)
```

However it's look slower than

```
def weightedL2(a, b, w):
    q = a-b
    return np.sqrt((w*q*q).sum())
```

Answer (score 1):

The present version of scipy (v1.9.3 as of writing) supports weighted L2 distance. From [scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean.html#scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean)

[image]

where: w(N,) array_like, optional

The weights for each value in u and v. Default is None, which gives each value a weight of 1.0