# How does Matlab apply weight in its Euclidean distance weight function?

Tags: matlab, octave

Does anyone know how Matlab’s `Z=dist(W,P)` works?  The [Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/dist.html) does not specify an algorithm that uses the weight matrix, W.

I am using Octave and trying to mimic the behavior.  So far, this [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079563/how-does-condensed-distance-matrix-work-pdist) helped me to prove that Octave’s `Z=squareform(pdist(P'))` is equivalent to Matlab’s `Z=dist(P)`.  I can also designate the elements of Z using a couple of for loops:

```
function z=dist(w,p)
    for i=1:size(p,2)
        for j=1:size(p,2)
            u=p(:,i);
            v=p(:,j);
            z(i,j)=sum((u-v).^2).^0.5;
        end
    end
end
```

However, I am unable to find any online documentation on the weight matrix, W.  I cannot simply multiply the output of `squareform(pdist(P'))` by W because the dimensions do not match.  I have attempted to premultiply W, e.g. `sqrt(W*(P(:,1)-P(:,2)).^2)`, like [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860850/euclidean-distance-with-weights) but the output magnitudes are wrong.

Here is an example using Matlab:

```
P=     
9     7    10
10    1    10
2     3     2
10    6    10

W=      
10    9     5     8
5     2    10    10

>> D = dist(P)
   0      10.0995    1.0000
10.0995      0      10.3441
1.0000    10.3441      0

>> D = dist(W,P)
3.8730     9.0000    3.7417
12.0000    8.3666   12.3693
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the *Neural Network Toolbox* is implemented in Matlab itself, so you can just look at those source files and figure it out.

If you open `dist` by entering `edit dist` in the command window, you see that it calls `dist.apply` or `dist.distance` to do the actual work, and the latter again `dist.apply`. Therefore, my guess is that what you are looking for can be found on line 9 of

```
toolbox/nnet/nnet/nndistance/+dist/apply.m
```

Type `edit dist.apply` in the command window to see it.

Comment: well... this answer only helps if one got access to a matlab installation :(